# Personalização do Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Olá, comecei a estudar programação a pouco tempo e sempre acabo ficando meio perdido nos códigos. Só que ai eu percebi que os espaçamentos no meu visual code são menores e é literalmente isso que faz eu me perder durante as aulas.
Então gostaria de saber como deixar igual ao do pessoal que ensina, que é quase que um padrão ser assim:

O do pessoal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu: 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na barra de status (no lado inferior direito) tem a opção de quantos espaços utilizar para indentação. Escolha 4 espaços e então use a opção Formatar Documento do seu menu de contexto (ou CTRL + SHIFT + I).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema no seu caso é a fonte, você precisa utilizar uma [fonte monoespaçada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonte_monoespa%C3%A7ada) para que todo caractere tenha o mesmo tamanho. Experimente por exemplo a fonte `Courier New` (que existe por padrão no Windows) ou a `Consolas`, basta abrir as configurações do editor de texto e modificar a fonte padrão.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou bastante!